# converting a matrix of data type double into binary image

Tags: matlab

i am working on fuzzy edge detector.after applying fuzzyfication  and defuzzyfication i have an matrix of same size as that of image. But that matrix is of double data type and values in this matrix are 0 or 1. I want to display this matrix as a binary image.  Here is code that i  had tried where rff is defuzzyfied  matrix.

```
>> rff2=uint8(rff);
>> rff3=im2bw(rff2);
>> imshow(rff3);
```

It is showing a blank image. But i want to have an edge image.

Answer (score 0):

Using the data type 'uint8', matlab expects the value to be between 0 and intmax. Your image has values 0 and 1, which is full black and nearly full black. Without knowing what exactly your input is, this should work:

```
%some random data, which hopefully matches your datatype
rff=repmat(randi(2,100,100)-1,[1,1,3]);
%convert to black and white double
rff2=im2bw(rff);
%optional step, we know that rff contains only 0 and 1, convert to logical
rff3=logical(rff2)
%display image
imshow(rff3);
```

Comment: Wouldn't `imshow(uint8(255 * rff))` work as well?  I don't have MATLAB in front of me and I have had little luck getting Octave to run.

Comment: @EdS.: For double input in range 0..1 this is correct. I prefer my solution because 'im2bw' will either produce the correct result or throw an expeption, your code will calculate invalid results if the input image is already an integer type. For this reason, I would always use one of the `im2*` functions to convert an image. Obviously, if it does not run on octave you have to find another solution.